# MidTier process account should have 'Full Read' permission on all associated SPWebApplications

Tags: 2013, permissions, service-application, powerpivot

I'm getting a Health Rule throwing the error in the title. Full details on this:

> MidTier process account should have 'Full Read' permission on all associated SPWebApplications

It also gives [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230899%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) for reference, basically saying that the Service App Identity for the PowerPivot Service Application needs to have "Read-Only" permissions to all web applications.

I've determined this by examining the application pool that the PowerPivot SA (PPSA) is running under, going to Configure Service Accounts and finding the account for that application pool.

I've added this account to have read-only permissions under "User Policy" for each and every web application and the health rule still persists.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've run a full crawl and rebooted the box in addition to attempting the "Auto Fix" for the rule.

Comment: Have you run the Health Analyzer Jobs, which populates you list of issues?

Comment: @BennySkogberg Yep, re-run Analyzer jobs, re-created service application as well. Problem persists.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue, I've given the user full read and the error still occurs.

Comment: Could you double check the account under CA > Security > Credential Management. Look for "PowerPivot Service Application"

Answer (score 1):

You should have two accounts for a proper setup of PowerPivot Service Application.

> SQL Server Analysis Services (PowerPivot) service is a Windows service that provides PowerPivot data processing and query support on an application server. The login account for this service is always specified during SQL Server Setup when you install Analysis Services in SharePoint integrated mode.

The second account is the app pool account, which is the one you probably have given full read permission after the service have been configured during installation.

If you have made your updates anywhere else than in Central Admin, the changes won't have any effect.

Also the account updating permissions will fail if it's not a Local Administrator on each server running the application, and the web apps.

When everything is updated, you need to run the **PowerPivot Configuration timer job** in Central Admin to make the changes.

Source: [Configure PowerPivot Service Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210642.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I checked this out today, and it comes down to the rule is broken for Claims-enabled Web Applications. Just validate that the account does have Full Read and disable the health analyzer rule (which the check and/or automatic repair will not work).

[PowerPivot Mid-Tier Process Account Does Not have Full Read](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2015/01/powerpivot-mid-tier-process-account-not-full-read/)